# How to share post to Facebook using Feed Dialog v2.11

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want my site users to share a custom post to their Facebook timelines **using Feed Dialog**. But I am stuck with permission issues. **The post_id is not coming after the user successfully shared the post**. **The post_id requires the app to have publish_actions granted, as per the Facebook doc** (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog).
[Snapshot of the feed-dialog doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgXdN.png)

**But when I tried to give the permission in the App Review section by adding publish_actions, it says that my app should not be using publish_actions to using Feed Dialog feature. Both of the documents are contradicts each other**. I am confused. 
[Snapshot shows where it denies to use publish_actions permission for Feed Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nz8j.png)
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

Please guide me if I am missing something at this point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you need the post id for? The dialogs are meant to be a way of posting that gives users maximum control, and doesn’t require any permissions. And Facebook will simply not grant you the use of that permission for this purpose only. If your app was already using this permission to post via API in other place, then you could get the post id back from the dialog as an “added bonus.” But if not, and you are using the dialogs only - then you should not really need a post id, and therefor you don’t get one.

Comment: Hi there! Well, I need the post_id to confirm that a user has successfully shared the post and I am maintaining a database table where I am storing the post_id against the user which helps me to track the users, who have shared the post.

Do you know in any other way I could be able achieve this (using Feed Dialog)? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to know who shared the post?

Comment: There is no other way. And I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to force people to share something to get to content, or incentivize/reward them in any way.

Comment: Hi @CBroe and WizKid, well I am not forcing any users to share something, its completely optional. But I just wanted to make a record of those who will share my post, that's it. Ok thanks.